# Searching through 1000s of links quickly Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a program that searches through Imgur link URLs and saves the ones that are made up of a specified list of characters where the image actually exists. I have 6 letters that are 100% in the link and am trying to run through all combinations with those 6 characters + 1 extra unknown character (a to z, 0 to 9).
For example: [www.imgur.com/gallery/BZmO8Ha](https://www.imgur.com/gallery/BZmO8Ha)

I was wondering if there was a quicker way to do this other than opening heaps of Python shells for a small amount of letters each?
Heres the code I've got currently:

```
import requests
from itertools import permutations

letters = 'BZmO8H'
letter_list = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890'

for letter in letter_list:
    new_list = letters+letter
    print(new_list)
    for per in permutations(new_list, 7):
        link = ''.join(per)
        print(link)
        r = requests.head("http://imgur.com/{}".format(link))
        print(r.status_code)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            file = open('links.txt', 'a')
            file.write("www.imgur.com/gallery/{}\n".format(link))
            file.close()
            print("Image Found. Added to File")
        elif r.status_code == 404:
            print("No Image")
        else:
            print("ERROR, SOMETHING WENT WRONG")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So one thing that would make this a lot faster is don't open and append to the file every single time that is going to take forever.

Save it to memory:

Do something like this:

```
import requests
from itertools import permutations

letters = 'BZmO8H'
letter_list = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890'

imgur_links = []

for letter in letter_list:
    new_list = letters+letter
    print(new_list)
    for per in permutations(new_list, 7):
        link = ''.join(per)
        print(link)
        r = requests.head("http://imgur.com/{}".format(link))
        print(r.status_code)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            imgur_links .append("www.imgur.com/gallery/{}\n".format(link))
            print("Image Found. Added to File")
        elif r.status_code == 404:
            print("No Image")
        else:
            print("ERROR, SOMETHING WENT WRONG")
file = open('links.txt', 'a')
file.write(imgur_links)
file.close()
```

This will load a maximum of 36 images, also you may want to get uppercase characters as well, which will make this a total of 62 which should be really fast, you could parallelize the requests using Asyncio or something as well, but it's probably overkill for so few requests.

Comment: Thanks, didn't even realise the capitalisation made a difference. I might not of made it clear but the letters aren't in order so it could be in any order. Meaning there are 1000s of combinations. Thats where my problem is, with the amount of different cominbations

Comment: Ok so your letters = 'BZmO8H' you are just using for your example but you might have thousands of different combinations of that string?  Is it an Anagram, or just totally random digits?

Comment: the letters = 'BZmO8H' are all in it, plus one random character which I do not know. So in total there is 7 characters in a random order.

Comment: Ah sorry it's late for me, I totally missed the permutations part.  Ok well there are a few issues here, one is you might run out of memory(but I think even at thousands you should still be fine if you have 8 gigs+ of memory in your system)

I would also use Leonel's advice and use grequests, seems pretty easy.  What that will do is essentially tell your code to launch lots of requests concurrently so you don't have to wait for each request individually.  You also want to not append to file as you could get race conditions, so the in memory solution is still the way to go.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the help, I'll have a look into grequests/gevent

Answer (score 3):

This is really slow because you are spending most of the time waiting for replies from imgur. You could speed this up quite a bit by dividing the permutations to check using threads so you could do a bunch of requests in parallel. An even better alternative would be to use async programming using asyncio/twisted/tornado/whatever.

Another alternative, which is probably the best, is to use **grequests** which is just like requests but async using gevent:
https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests

Whatever you choose make sure to rate limit the requests somehow because you will flood imgur with requests otherwise.

Comment: Ok thanks, any recommended guides/example for getting into gevent?